# How do I resize my menu bar when the screen size changes?

Tags: html, css, resize

I want to resize a top menu bar when the screen resizes. I have tried the usual @media screen method but it doesn't seem to work. Please help me find a solution?

Here's the HTML:

```
<p id='nav-menu' style='text-align:center; '>
  <a href="#">Food & Drink</a>
  <a href="#">Arts</a>
  <a href="#">Culture</a>
  <a href="#">Active</a>
  <a href="#">Areas</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
</p>
```

Thanks

Comment: Could you add your CSS along with the question, as it may be a problem there.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily done it by @media

Make sure you have this code in header

```
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* Your code is here*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use media queries correctly, it should work. Let's say you want the links to be in a column instead of a row, you could do :

```
/* Feel free to change the width */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    #nav-menu {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I tried the flex one and it worked, but I don't want to arrange them in a column. Other functions I've tried don't seem to work though (i.e. applying a fixed width).

The CSS that I'm using to format them is below - is there something in it that's interfering with the @media function?

```
#nav-menu {font-size:16px; line-height:32px; 
                width:720px; height:32px; margin:0 auto; padding:0;}

#nav-menu a {display:block; text-decoration: none; color:#000000; width:100px; height:32px; margin:0 0px 0 10px; float:left; border: 3px solid #808080}
```

Thanks